# Google Cloud SQL - Database instance storage size increased dramatically everyday

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a database instance (MySQL 8) on Google Cloud and since 20 days ago, the instance's storage usage just keeps increasing (approx 2Gb every single day!).
But I couldn't find out why.

What I have done:

1. Take a look at Point-in-time recovery "Point-in-time recovery" option, it's already disabled.
2. Binary logs is not enabled.
3. Check the actual database size and I see my database is just only 10GB in size
4. No innodb_per_table flag, so it must be "false" by default

Storage usage chart:

[image: chart]

Database flags:

[image]

The actual database size is 10GB, now the storage usage takes up to 220GB! That's a lot of money!

I couldn't resolve this issue, please give me some ideal tips. Thank you!

Comment: Please ask database admin related question on the dedicated DBA sister site of SO, not on the programming focused SO!

Comment: Go to the audit logs and search what changed on November 5th. If nothing, have a look on a released that you deployed that day. You have something similar to a memory leak, but in database (object never cleaned, new index of constantly growing data,...)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere unfortunately nothing related to the significant database growth found in the audit logs... Still I dont see anything wrong with the code since it doesn't update any records in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem is in a Wordpress theme's function called "related_products" which just read and write every instance of the products that user comes accross (it would be millions per day) and makes the database physically blew up.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thing happen to me about a year ago. I couldn't determine any root cause of the huge increase in storage size. I restarted the server and the problem stopped. None of my databases experienced any significant increase in size. My best guess is that some runaway process causes the binlog to blow up.